# Query sellingPlanGroups using graphql on shopify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, subscription

I have created 2 sellingPlanGroups using Shopify GraphQL App and the query to get data on the app is normal. But when I use this statement in my custom app it returns null. How to resolve this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT7IL.png)

I add scopes = "write_products, read_customer_payment_methods, read_own_subscription_contracts, write_own_subscription_contracts" to query but it return nul

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is written incorrectly. **sellingPlanGroups** is plural and returns zero, one or more results, up to ten for you. Try asking for edges and their node.

```
query{
    sellingPlanGroups(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          appId
          id
          name
          description
          summary
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why on Shopify GraphiQL App I query results like this.
{
  "data": {
    "sellingPlanGroups": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "appId": null,
            "description": null,
            "name": "Subscribe and save",
            "summary": "3 delivery frequencies, 5-15% discount",
            "id": "gid://shopify/SellingPlanGroup/1276576063"
          }
        },
       ......
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 When I query the custom app, it doesn't show any sellingplan id.